# Create dictionary with length of string as key and string as value without import statement?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

Can you create a dictionary with length of string as key and string as value without an import statement?

With an import statement it would look like this:

```
strings =  ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"] 
from itertools import groupby
dict_of_len = {k: set(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(strings, key = len), len)}
print(dict_of_len)
```

Output:

```
{3: ['zas'], 4: ['zone', 'form', 'libe'], 5: ['theta'], 7:['abigail']}
```

If possible I would like two options, where for one of the options the value is a list of values, and another option where the value is a set of values.

I tried this by myself but I keep getting difficulties when there are multiple values for the same key.

**one of my failed attempts**

```
for i in strings:
   dictio = dict()
   set1 = set()
   set1.add(i)
   dictio[len(i)] = set1
print(dictio)
```

output

```
{3: {'zas'}}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: thx @khelwood I've editted it

Comment: @quamrana I will give one of my failed attempt in my edit. Pleas don't be to harsh because I'm just a beginner

Comment: We are not here to be harsh to you. We just want future programmers to be able to see how you described your requirements and what code you managed to write as you thought about what needed to be done.

Comment: But, yes, can you see how `dictio` is being reset back to an empty `dict` each time through the loop? Compare that to the answers which create an empty `dict` once before the `for` loop.

Comment: @quamrana yes, that was one of the problems that I couldn't solve, but I've noticed it.

Comment: Excellent!. Now I know you have noticed that, I can hope that many future programmers will also notice this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easier with a defaultdict, but you can do it without any imports.

To use lists as values:

```
strings =  ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"] 
dict_of_len = {}
for string in strings:
    ls = len(string)
    if ls in dict_of_len:
        dict_of_len[ls].append(string)
    else:
        dict_of_len[ls] = [string]
```

To use sets as values, much the same but with a set instead of a list, and with `add` instead of `append`.

```
strings =  ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"] 
dict_of_len = {}
for string in strings:
    ls = len(string)
    if ls in dict_of_len:
        dict_of_len[ls].add(string)
    else:
        dict_of_len[ls] = {string}
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much @khelwood! I've struggled a lot trying to figure this out

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```py
result = {}
for s in strings:
    result.setdefault(len(s), []).append(s)
```

Comment: thank you @a_guest I didn't know that existed!

Answer (score 1):

Use `setdefault` method of `dict`:

```
strings =  ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"] 

# List version
dict_of_len = {}
for word in strings:
    dict_of_len.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word)
print(dict_of_len)


# Sets version
dict_of_len = {}
for word in strings:
    s = dict_of_len.setdefault(len(word), set())
    dict_of_len[len(word)] = s.union([word])
print(dict_of_len)
```

Output:

```
{4: ['zone', 'form', 'libe'], 7: ['abigail'], 5: ['theta'], 3: ['zas']}
{4: {'libe', 'form', 'zone'}, 7: {'abigail'}, 5: {'theta'}, 3: {'zas'}}
```